# Why is $\frac{\partial \bar f }{\partial z} = 0$ for an analytic function $f$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

> Why is $\frac{\partial \bar f }{\partial z} = 0$ for an analytic function $f$?

I understand that, for an analytic function $f, \frac{\partial f }{\partial \bar z} = 0$, but I do not get why the above is true. How can one justify "flipping" the complex conjugate sign (and also without actually defining $\frac{\partial \bar f }{\partial z}$ to be $\overline{\frac{\partial f }{\partial \bar z}}$)?

I get that $\frac{\partial \bar f }{\partial z} = \frac 12 (\frac{\partial \bar f }{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial \bar f }{\partial y})$, but I am not sure how this is related to Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: It's the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first let's write the CR equations with $f = u+iv$. 
$$
u_x = v_y
$$
$$
-u_y = v_x
$$
Then, as you noted in your last line, 
$$
\frac{\partial \bar{f}}{\partial z} \sim \frac{\partial \bar{f}}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial \bar{f}}{\partial y}
$$
dropping the constant factor because we want to show this is $0$ anyway. Substituting for our functions $u$ and $v$, we have
\begin{gather*}
\frac{\partial \bar{f}}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big[u-iv\Big]-i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Big[u-iv\Big] \\
= u_x-iv_x-i\big(u_y-iv_y\big)\\
= u_x-v_y - i(v_x + u_y)
\end{gather*}
This expression is $0$ by CR equations.

Answer (score 2):

Just write $\overline {f}=u-iv$ where $u$ and $v$ are the real and imaginary parts of $f$. Then $2\frac {\partial \overline {f}} {\partial z}$ becomes $(u_x-v_y)-i(u_y+v_x)$ after some simplification. Both the terms are $0$ by C-R equations.

Comment: Sir please look at my question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3010046/analytic-function-must-be-free-from-barz