# Analytic function must be free from $\bar{z}.$

Tags: complex-analysis

How can i say that analytic function must be free from $\bar{z}?$ I verified it for many examples like $\bar{z}, z^2+\bar{z} $ etc and found that the results seems to be true according to me . I am thinking  like as if any complex function contains $\bar{z}$  term in any form(obviously in nontrivial form  unlike $\bar{z}-\bar{z}$) then that terms is never analytic and hence whole function is also never analytic. Please suggest . Thanks .

Comment: $(\Re^2z+\Im^2z)/\overline z$? But seriously, we want $\partial  /\partial \overline z=0$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen      its in trivial form... its nothing but $z$ function.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I am saying its in nontrivial form

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting question, which is usually glossed over when doing complex calculus in $z$ and $\bar z$ terms. It is also not so clear what the actual claim is. E.g., the function $q(z):={\rm conjugate}(\bar z)$ is analytic $\ldots$

I'm going to argue in the following setup: Let
$$\Phi:\quad\Omega\to{\mathbb C},\qquad(z,\zeta)\to\Phi(z,\zeta)$$
be defined on the  domain $\Omega\subset{\mathbb C}^2$. Assume that $\Phi$ is (i) a $C^1$ function of its four real variables $(x, y, \xi,\eta)$, and is (ii)   separately analytic in each of the two complex variables $z$ and $\zeta$, meaning that the partial functions
$$z\mapsto\Phi(z,\zeta_0),\qquad {\rm resp.,}\qquad \zeta\mapsto\Phi(z_0,\zeta)$$
are analytic  functions of $z$, resp., of $\zeta$, as long as $(z,\zeta_0)\in\Omega$, resp., $(z_0,\zeta)\in\Omega$. Such a $\Phi$ could be given as a series, or as an "analytic expression" in terms of the variables $z$ and $\zeta$.

Given such a $\Phi$ we consider the function
$$f(z):=\Phi(z,\bar z)\qquad(z\in\Omega')\ ,\tag{1}$$
whose domain is the open set $\Omega':=\bigl\{z\in{\mathbb C}\bigm| (z,\bar z)\in\Omega\bigr\}\subset{\mathbb C}$. We now pose the following question:

What are necessary and sufficient conditions on $\Phi$ making  $f$  an analytic function on $\Omega'$?

**Claim.** The function $f$ is analytic on $\Omega'$ **iff** $$\Phi_{.2}(z,\bar z)=0\qquad\forall\>z\in\Omega'\ .$$
Here $\Phi_{.2}$ denotes the partial derivative of $\Phi$ with respect to its second complex variable.

*Proof.* Fix a $z\in\Omega'$, and let $h$ be a complex increment variable. Then
$$\eqalign{f(z+h)-f(z)&=\Phi(z+h,\bar z+\bar h)-\Phi(z,\bar z)\cr  &=\Phi_{.1}(z,\bar z)\>h+\Phi_{.2}(z,\bar z)\>\bar h\ +o\bigl(|h|\bigr)\qquad(h\to0\in{\mathbb C})\ .\cr}\tag{2}$$
Here we just have used the assumptions on $\Phi$ and the definition of derivative. Now the main part of the right hand side of $(2)$ is a complex linear function of $h$, i.e., of the form $h\mapsto \lambda h$ for some $\lambda\in{\mathbb C}$, iff  $\Phi_{.2}(z,\bar z)=0$.$\quad\square$

When we are applying this principle  there will be given a function $f$ defined in the form $(1)$. By abuse of notation one then does not explicitly  introduce an auxiliary variable $\zeta$. Instead one just considers the $\bar z$ appearing in $(1)$ as an "independent complex variable" and formally differentiates the expression $\Phi(z,\bar z)$ with respect to this variable. In this way one arrives at the handy condition
$${\partial\Phi(z,\bar z)\over\partial\bar z}=0\qquad\forall z\in\Omega'\ .$$

Comment: "which is usually glossed over when doing complex calculus in z and z¯ terms. It is also not so clear what the actual claim is." No. The approach you suggest is ingenious but, to "sell" it, it is not necessary to cast aspersions on the way complex analysis is taught.

Comment: @Did: I didn't want to cast any aspersions on the way complex analysis is taught. But it is a fact that, e.g., nobody really knows or cares what he is doing when using Wirtinger calculus.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter conjugate$\bar{z}$ is analytic but i said it is not in non trivial form...its in trivial form...